# Why is this RecyclerView ItemClickSupport 's constructor a singletone?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, onclicklistener

https://www.littlerobots.nl/blog/Handle-Android-RecyclerView-Clicks/

```
    private ItemClickSupport(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
        mRecyclerView.setTag(R.id.item_click_support, this);
        mRecyclerView.addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(mAttachListener);
    }


    public static ItemClickSupport addTo(RecyclerView view) {
        ItemClickSupport support = (ItemClickSupport) 
        view.getTag(R.id.item_click_support);
        if (support == null) {
            support = new ItemClickSupport(view);
        }
        return support;
    }
```

I am very glad to find this supporting RecyclerView Click source and it works find.

But I wonder why is constructor defined as a singleton.

Is is the same reason of creating new RecyclerViewAdapter for another `RecyclerView` in same class?

I read a comment that is not recommended one adapter for various `RecyclerView` because of single responsibility principle.

Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 0):

That's not a Singleton.

In simple terms, a Singleton is a class that is restricted to only a *single* instance. It's impossible for there to be a second instance of that class, which is why Singletons have a commonly named `static` `getInstance()` method.

However, the class you're asking about, `ItemClickSupport` isn't the same. Unlike a Singleton, it can have many instances of itself. The `addTo()` method is simply making sure that every `RecyclerView` possesses exactly **one** instance of `ItemClickSupport`.

However, that doesn't make it a Singleton because as long as there's another `RecyclerView` being passed into `ItemClickSupport#addTo()`, there will be another instance of `ItemClickSupport`.